# Css + Jquery in order to achieve this overlap

Tags: jquery, html, css, styles

[My jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2bU5D)

I have 3 parents, that will contain an undefined number of children, (parents are floating) children are relative, the scheme looks like this:

```
-----Parent-----   ------Parent------  ----Parent----
|    Child     |   |     Child       | |   Child    |
|    Child     |   |     Child       | |   Child    |
|    Child     |   |     Child       | |   Child    |
|    Child     |   |     Child       | --------------
----------------   -------------------
```

On mouse over, children will resize to a bigger height, but i want them to overlap, i don't want to extend the parent.

My css looks like this:

```
    .parent{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:296px;
    background-color:pink;
    margin-right:10px;
}

    .child{
        position:relative;
        height:60px;
        margin-bottom:10px;
        background-image:url("../images/theme_test.png");
    }
```

I tried to use top, the Y position but it is not working, the children bellow will go down.

Comment: please create a jsFiddle containing the your CSS and HTML markup

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2bU5D/

Answer (score 2):

There you go: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2bU5D/8/).

I've updated the positions using `margin`s and notice 2 things:

1. I had to change the `z-index` so the hovered element will be on top
2. I've created a special treatment for the last child - making it grow up instead of down so it won't make the parent longer

This is the `mouseenter` event:

```
$('.child').mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).css('z-index',5);
        if($(this).is(':last-child')){ // check if this is the last child
            $(this).animate({
                height: "80px",
                'margin-top': "-20px" // grow upwards..
            }, 250 );
        }else{
           $(this).animate({
                height: "80px",
                'margin-bottom': "-10px" // grow down wards..
            }, 250 );
        }
    })
```

`mouseout` is the exact opposite.

Comment: Please don't rely exclusively on a link to a third-party site, even one as reliable as jsFiddle. It would be better to post the code here and use the fiddle as a support.

Comment: updated - added the mouseenter event and some comments to explain

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar in the past. You don't really need any javascript or jquery.

What you will need is to set relative position on every child (which you have done) and create inside every child another container with absolute position. Then just add some css code to change height of this container on hover and also to adjust z-index properly.

**Update:**
I've updated your code posted before. Just used last-child css to move last child up instead of only increasing height. Result is same as using javascript, but personally i would avoid using JS when not needed.

Here is updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2bU5D/11/) (Added transitions and border - looks nice :) )

CSS:

```
.parent{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    background-color:pink;
    margin-right:10px;
}
.child{
    position:relative;
    height: 60px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
.child > .content {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background-color:cyan;
    z-index: 1;
}

.child:hover > .content {
    background: red;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 2;
}

.child:last-child:hover > .content {
    height: 100px;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, its not. Try adding border to parent class and see that nothing happends. Its correct.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that the children exceed the size of the parent.. I think he wants the children to stay inside the parent

Comment: My bad, in that case jquery will be only way. I think he only wants other children to stay in place :)

Comment: Now it does the same as your JS.

Comment: NICE JOB :) i've updated your post with transitions and borders- look at the new jsFiddle

Answer (score 0):

I edited Yotam's fiddle by implementing a couple `if` statements to prevent changing of the parent div's height (his would if you move quickly over from one to the other) and to prevent the children from being animated over and over sometimes if the mouse moves quickly from one to another. This is done by checking to see if another child in the column is currently being animated and not allowing animation until it is done: `if(!animating)`. The only problem occurs if one moves quickly from one to another so the `mouseenter` occurs before the other stops animating. You can decide which you like better. [Here is the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2bU5D/9/)

Using CSS would be awesome like Majky said would be awesome, that's how I would do it personally